# Why does export const work but export function does not?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to ensure that the same instance of `vue-router` is available in multiple places in my app.

The **vue.router.js** file exports the router like this:

```
export function createVueRouter() {
    return createRouter({
        history: createWebHistory('/')
        routes: [//array of routes]
    });
}
```

In my main **app.js** file (or **main.js** if you prefer) it is used like this:

```
import {createVueRouter} from './router/vue/vue.router.js';
const router = createVueRouter();
app.use(router);
```

The Vue app now has access to the `vue-router`. I now want the same vue-router to be available in an independent JS file. But the following does not work:

**resusable.js**

```
import {createVueRouter} from './router/vue/vue.router.js';
const router = createVueRouter();
//....
if (isLoggedInBasic !== true) {
            return await router.push({name: "Signin"})
}
```

It creates a new instance of the `vue-router` and the `router.push` does not take the user to the `Signin` route (but the URL in the address bar does change).

If I change **vue.router.js** export to the following, it works fine all the files with the same router instance being shared between them.

```
export const VueRouter = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory('/')
    routes: [//array of routes]
})
```

I cannot understand what is the difference and why it works when `export const` is used rather than just `export function ()`

Comment: When you call `createVueRouter()` it calls `createRouter()`. That creates a new instance. Perhaps I don't understand the question but the difference seems obvious. In the example that works the way you want, you only call `createRouter()` once.

Comment: @Pointy Why does the `createRouter()` not get called twice then, one in `app.js` and then again in `reusable.js`, thus creating two instances?

Comment: When you export the **result** of calling `createRouter()`, nothing is going to call it again.  The module code is only run once, not on each `import`.

Comment: @Pointy okay, so I understood it wrongly then. I thought `const VueRouter` was now the function `createRouter()` itself. I didn't realise it was the **result** of calling that function. Could you kindly point me to any docs that explain this stuff?

Comment: if you're exporting the `router` object, it will be shared between all files that imports it. If you export the function that creates that object, even if shared, it will create a separate router object each time it is called.

Comment: In any context in JavaScript, an expression like `functionName(...)` is a **call** to that function, and the value in the larger context is whatever that function returns.

Comment: To answer the question 'what is the docs explain this stuff?' It's just the basics of javascript. You can follow these questions to find your own answer. What is function in JS? How to declare and execute a function in JS? What is import and export in JS?

Comment: Thank you all for your kind explanations. Very helpful of you.